# an openapi client jar, generated for scala-akka by openapi-generator-maven-plugin, causes canBuildFromIterableViewMapLike() not found, under Zeppelin

Tags: scala, akka, apache-zeppelin

I'm generating a *Scala* client jar with `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin` so that my Zeppelin will be able to execute this sample of code,

`openapi-generator-maven-plugin` offers few generators for *Scala*, and recommends to choose `scala-akka`.

It requires to produce a complicated piece of client code:

```scala
%spark
import java.util.Map;
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.invoker._
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.model.Commune;
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.api.CogControllerApi;
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.invoker.CollectionFormats._
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.invoker.ApiKeyLocations._

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

val apiInvoker = ApiInvoker()
val cogService = CogControllerApi("http://localhost:9090")
val request = cogService.obtenirCommunes(2022);

val response = apiInvoker.execute(request)

response.onComplete {
    case Success(ApiResponse(code, content, headers)) =>
        System.out.println(s"Status code: $code}")
        System.out.println(s"Response headers: ${headers.mkString(", ")}")
        System.out.println(s"Response body: $content")
        
    case Failure(error @ ApiError(code, message, responseContent, cause, headers)) =>
        System.err.println("Exception when calling CogControllerApi#obtenirCommunes")
        System.err.println(s"Status code: $code}")
        System.err.println(s"Reason: $responseContent")
        System.err.println(s"Response headers: ${headers.mkString(", ")}")
        error.printStackTrace();

    case Failure(exception) => 
        System.err.println("Exception when calling CogControllerApi#obtenirCommunes")
        exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

With eventually a run failure under *Zeppelin*:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom scala.collection.compat.package$.canBuildFromIterableViewMapLike()'
  at fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.invoker.ApiInvoker.makeUri(ApiInvoker.scala:213)
  at fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.invoker.ApiInvoker.execute(ApiInvoker.scala:226)
  ... 44 elided
```

### How I've managed things:

Its generated `openapi.jar` has this content:

```
jar tf openapi-client-1.0.0.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
fr/
fr/ecoemploi/
fr/ecoemploi/application/
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/model/
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/model/Commune$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/model/Commune.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/CogControllerApi$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/ComptesCollectivitesControllerApi.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/ComptesCollectivitesControllerApi$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/EnumsSerializers$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/EnumsSerializers.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/CovidControllerApi.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/EquipementControllerApi$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/CovidControllerApi$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/EnumsSerializers$EnumNameSerializer.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/IntercoControllerApi$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/ActivitesControllerApi.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/EnumsSerializers$EnumNameSerializer$$anonfun$deserialize$1.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/ActivitesControllerApi$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/AssociationsControllerApi$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/IntercoControllerApi.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/EnumsSerializers$EnumNameSerializer$$anonfun$serialize$1.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/EquipementControllerApi.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/CogControllerApi.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/api/AssociationsControllerApi.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiRequest$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/CollectionFormat.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers$LocalDateSerializer$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers$DateTimeSerializer$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/NumericValue.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyCredentials.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/CustomContentTypes.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/CollectionFormats.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyValue.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers$DateTimeSerializer$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1$$anonfun$apply$1.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiError$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Credentials.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ParametersMap$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/CollectionFormats$CSV$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyCredentials$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiModel.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiMethods.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ParametersMap.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/BasicCredentials.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers$DateTimeSerializer$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiMethod.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyLocations$HEADER$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyValue$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiInvoker$$anonfun$unmarshallApiResponse$4.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiSettings.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyLocations$QUERY$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/CollectionFormats$SSV$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiInvoker$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers$LocalDateSerializer$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$2.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers$DateTimeSerializer$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1$$anonfun$apply$2.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiResponse.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiRequest.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyLocation.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiInvoker$ApiRequestImprovements.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/CollectionFormats$PIPES$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/UnitJSONSupport.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/BearerToken$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/BasicCredentials$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/NumericValue$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/MergedArrayFormat.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiResponse$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyLocations$COOKIE$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiMethod$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers$LocalDateSerializer$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$2$$anonfun$apply$4.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/BearerToken.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyLocations.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ResponseState$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiInvoker.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/CollectionFormats$TSV$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ArrayValues.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/CollectionFormats$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ResponseState$Error$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiError$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ParametersMap$ParametersMapImprovements.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiMethods$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/CollectionFormats$MULTI$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiInvoker$ApiMethodExtensions.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiKeyLocations$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiReturnWithHeaders.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiSettings$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ResponseState.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiError.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ResponseState$Success$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ApiError$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$2.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/ArrayValues$.class
fr/ecoemploi/application/etude/swagger/invoker/Serializers$LocalDateSerializer$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$2$$anonfun$apply$3.class
reference.conf
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/org.openapitools/
META-INF/maven/org.openapitools/openapi-client/
META-INF/maven/org.openapitools/openapi-client/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/org.openapitools/openapi-client/pom.properties
```

The `lib` folder accompanying the generated sources when they are compiled, has this content:

```
akka-actor_2.12-2.6.12.jar        json4s-core_2.12-3.6.7.jar               scalatest-core_2.12-3.2.3.jar
akka-http_2.12-10.2.3.jar         json4s-ext_2.12-3.6.7.jar                scalatest-diagrams_2.12-3.2.3.jar
akka-http-core_2.12-10.2.3.jar    json4s-jackson_2.12-3.6.7.jar            scalatest-featurespec_2.12-3.2.3.jar
akka-http-json4s_2.12-1.27.0.jar  json4s-scalap_2.12-3.6.7.jar             scalatest-flatspec_2.12-3.2.3.jar
akka-parsing_2.12-10.2.3.jar      junit-4-13_2.12-3.2.3.0.jar              scalatest-freespec_2.12-3.2.3.jar
akka-protobuf-v3_2.12-2.6.12.jar  junit-4.13.jar                           scalatest-funspec_2.12-3.2.3.jar
akka-stream_2.12-2.6.12.jar       paranamer-2.8.jar                        scalatest-funsuite_2.12-3.2.3.jar
config-1.4.1.jar                  reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar               scalatest-matchers-core_2.12-3.2.3.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar             scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.4.1.jar   scalatest-mustmatchers_2.12-3.2.3.jar
hpack-1.0.2.jar                   scalactic_2.12-3.2.3.jar                 scalatest-propspec_2.12-3.2.3.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar     scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.8.0.jar        scalatest-refspec_2.12-3.2.3.jar
jackson-core-2.9.8.jar            scala-library-2.12.13.jar                scalatest-shouldmatchers_2.12-3.2.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar        scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.2.jar  scalatest-wordspec_2.12-3.2.3.jar
joda-convert-2.2.0.jar            scala-reflect-2.12.12.jar                scala-xml_2.12-1.2.0.jar
joda-time-2.10.1.jar              scalatest_2.12-3.2.3.jar                 ssl-config-core_2.12-0.4.2.jar
json4s-ast_2.12-3.6.7.jar         scalatest-compatible-3.2.3.jar
```

It appears that on the `spark.jars` attribute of the *Zeppelin* *Scala* interpreter, I shall not only add
`openapi-client-1.0.0.jar`, but also some of these jars listed.

But not all of them, of course...
I have joined those to `spark.jars` attribute of Zeppelin:

```
spark.jars  /home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/openapi-client-1.0.0.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/akka-actor_2.12-2.6.12.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/akka-http_2.12-10.2.3.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/akka-http-core_2.12-10.2.3.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/akka-http-json4s_2.12-1.27.0.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/akka-parsing_2.12-10.2.3.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/akka-protobuf-v3_2.12-2.6.12.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/akka-stream_2.12-2.6.12.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/config-1.4.1.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/hpack-1.0.2.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/paranamer-2.8.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/joda-convert-2.2.0.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/joda-time-2.10.1.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/json4s-ast_2.12-3.6.7.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/json4s-core_2.12-3.6.7.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/json4s-ext_2.12-3.6.7.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/json4s-jackson_2.12-3.6.7.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/json4s-scalap_2.12-3.6.7.jar,
/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/dev/GenerationOpenAPI/target/generated-sources/swagger/scala/target/lib/ssl-config-core_2.12-0.4.2.jar
```

### May be I souldn't use `scala-akka` for client generator?

Or, am I on the wrong way for generation, and *Apache Zeppelin* requires another generator selection that `scala-akka`, for the openapi-client.jar to use with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Epilogue

*Scala* is a hell of incompatible jars, even in the middle of its `2.12.x` or `2.13.x` versions.

It happened that *Spark* (used by *Apache Zeppelin*) was using incompatible Scala jars from `scala.collection.compat` package, some coming through `com.google.protobuf`, did I red.

So the workaround is to create a fat jar relocating these classes elsewhere, renaming their packages.
Then, the `client-openapi.jar` created will be accepted.

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass></mainClass>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>reference.conf</resource>
            </transformer>

            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
          </transformers>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>com</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>repackaged.com.google.common</shadedPattern>

              <includes>
                <include>com.google.common.**</include>
              </includes>
            </relocation>

            <relocation>
              <pattern>com.google.protobuf</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>com.shaded.protobuf</shadedPattern>

              <includes>
                <include>com.google.protobuf.**</include>
              </includes>
            </relocation>

            <relocation>
              <pattern>scala.collection.compat</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>scala.shaded.compat</shadedPattern>

              <includes>
                <include>scala.collection.compat.**</include>
              </includes>
            </relocation>

            <relocation>
              <pattern>shapeless</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>shapelessshaded</shadedPattern>

              <includes>
                <include>shapeless.**</include>
              </includes>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```